# Bidirectional 4 cell Li-Ion battery pack

Tags: battery-charging, circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply

I went through the following application note from microchip that deals with designing a bidirectional power supply for charging a battery pack (**pages 16/30 and 17/30**).

The link: https://www.microchip.com/Developmenttools/ProductDetails/MCP1630RD-DDBK3

The application note says that when a power supply of 6.5V to 7V presents from the right side (J2 in the schematic), the circuit works as a boost converter to charge the battery pack.

1. Let's start from this point. To charge an Li-Ion battery pack, we need two loops (Constant current loop and a constant voltage loop ). At this configuration, we have only the current loop composed of **U4:A** and its surrounding components, In my behalf, I don't think that the voltage loop composed of **U3:B** will take effect in this configuration because it is placed at the input side of the boost configuration. So, where is the voltage loop when the circuit is in the boost configuration ?
2. When the circuit is concidered from left to right, the battery pack is concidered to be the input voltage to the rest of the circuit which is now working as a voltage mode buck converter (controlled by **U3:B** that is now at the output of the circuit). And the current flowing through the shunt resistors **R4 and R5** is now negative, so how does the current loop react to this current knowing that the OPAMP is fed only with a positive 5V ?

Comment: It certainly looks suspicious  without  Vbatt sense. Write to https://microchipsupport.force.com/s/support-resources?tabName=Community

Comment: To sense the battery voltage, they have used the  a divider network composed of R1 and R3 and they have connected it ot  the ADC of the MCU (PIN RA0 in the circuit of page 17/30 )

Comment: OK>, Then that's the feedback loop for CV

Comment: In that case, they sense the voltage of the battery, but how do they regulate the output voltage of the boost converter ? knowing that this pin has nothing to do with the PWM controller unit (MCP1630V). In fact I can agree with you if this charger is only a constant current charger, which means when the battery reaches the maximum voltage, instead of appying constant voltage charging, the software reduces the IREF through PIN RA6 till they reach a trickle charging current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This design uses PIN RA0 to measure Vbatt and sets Ibatt for the charge current in a continuous loop for each of the 4 modes.

Idle, Pre-charge, CC, CV, Idle Cutoff  < 100mA

[image]

Comment: Ok, so you agree with me that there is no voltage loop block to regulate the voltage charging state, and it uses only  the current loop to do that job. Thanks a lot Tony

Comment: Correct the voltage feedback and servo loop is software controlled